# Python wrapper "python-amazon-simple-product-api" using to create a new cart on Amazon

Tags: python, api, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to create a new cart on Amazon through using the Python wrapper "python-amazon-simple-product-api". The following code runs well.

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI
amazon = AmazonAPI("valid key","valid key","valid value")
product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B005M393OO', ResponseGroup="Large")
product.title
product.asin
```

Output:

> '1 X 12 Washing Machine Lint Traps Aluminum Mesh With Clamps'
>
> 'B010T3VSLW'

But, when I'm trying to create a new cart, I have the following:

```
amazon_cart = amazon.cart_create([{'offer_id':'B010T3VSLW','quantity': 1}])
```

Output: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ea7H.png)

So, the response is **"AWS.InvalidParameterValue is not a valid value for OfferListingId. Please change this value and retry your request."**
It seems that there is some mistake in the arguments I use for the function create_cart, i.e.

```
cart_create([{'offer_id':'B010T3VSLW','quantity': 1}]).
```

Does anybody know a correct way to create a new cart?

Thank you.

Comment: Here there is a solution for this problem: https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api/pull/80/files

Answer (score 0):

chane the value of offer_id into offer_listing_id rather than asin